# Como impedir POST de fora do servidor?

Tags: php, htaccess, segurança

Estou criando uma aplicação e não queria que algum espertinho pense em alterar o caminho de um `POST` html para enviar os valores que ele quiser, usei então um método em PHP:

```
        $referral=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; 
        $origin="https://google.com.br"; 
        $origin2="https://sitepermitido.com/arquivodeorigem.php";
        $refervalid=0; 
            // Testa se o formulário foi submetido da página original
            if($referral==$origin2) $refervalid=1; 
                if((!$refervalid)){
                // dados enviado de servidor externo?                       
                    echo "Acesso negado"; 
                    exit; 
                }
```

Mas vi muita gente dizendo que isto é inseguro, que alguém pode simplesmente "simular" um `refer` com curl ou algo do tipo.
Então vi um cara na net mandando usar o `.htacess`, assim:

```
<Directory /home/sportfacil/public_html/pastadaaplicação>
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
   AllowOverride All
   Order deny,allow

   Deny from all
   Allow from 127.0.0.1
   Allow from localhost
   Allow from ::1
</Directory>
```

Mas isso me retorno `erro 500`, tentei vários outros métodos no `.htacess` mas ele acaba bloqueando tudo, até mesmo que a página interna submeta o formulário.

Existe alguma maneira mais eficaz de prevenir um `action` externo?

Comment: O *espertinho* não precisa enviar um form pelo localhost, basta clicar em *inspecionar elemento*, encontrar o `form` e alterar o input que quiser... Voilá, agora temos um formulário violado enviado pelo mesmo `HTTP_REFERER`.

Comment: Ou ainda, ele nem precisa encontrar um form, ele pode criar o próprio dele, tudo que está do lado cliente é do "cliente", se a sua página é publica realmente não vejo motivo para proteger os dados assim, se a sua página é privada significa que a conta é do usuário, se o usuário está tendo acesso a dados no formulário que deveria ser restritos, então isto é uma falha sua na estratégia do desenvolvimento (desculpe a sinceridade), tem dados que realmente não são necessário ir para o front-end.

Comment: Então não existe um POST seguro?
todos podem ser violados!

Comment: @CassianoJosé o POST é irrelevante, o problema é os dados no POST. Se não tiverem dados pertinentes no `<form>` não há problema de segurança, o cara pode alterar o `action` pra mandar pro diabo, que ainda sim o diabo só vai receber dados que não afetam a segurança. COMO EU DISSE: Existe maneira de fazer a passagem de dados de maneira segura sem precisar enviar ao front-end. Outra coisa se a sua página é PUBLICA, nem precisa violar os forms, basta um BOT "baixar"  que tem o formulário e pronto seu dados foram comprometidos...

Comment: ...continuando, o que vai tornar seguro é o que VOCÊ EXPÕE no front-end, portanto o problema não é com os forms, MAS COMO VOCÊ PROJETOU.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<sup>Pelo menos foi engraçado ver como as pessoas postam besteiras tão grandes na internet. Quando é assim você cita a fonte.</sup>

Este código bloqueia o **seu** acesso interno e não o acesso de ninguém. Você é o `localhost`, não o usuário externo. Nenhum usuário externo se comunica com você pelo `localhost`, se fosse assim, todo mundo seria `localhost` e não haveria diferenciação entre os usuários acessando.

Esqueça, você não tem controle sobre o que os outros fazem nos computadores deles. Qualquer tentativa de se proteger de algo externo causará mais confusão. A única segurança que você pode dar é validar corretamente todo dado que vem de fora. Isto depende de cada caso mas você não pode validar intenção, só o dado recebido.

Não há meio eficaz de impedir o envio de dados da forma que o usuário quiser, eficaz é garantir que todos os aspectos dos dados recebidos estejam de acordo com o que você quer.

Você não consegue saber de onde vem a informação, ela é disfarçável, sempre. Até mesmo o IP é possível falsificar se quem fizer isto não quiser receber uma resposta do seu servidor.

Eu recomendo você retirar a "segurança" que usa hoje. Ela é melhor porque ela tenta validar a informação, mas ela está criando um problema que você não vê. Você está impedindo alguns acessos legítimos.

Quando faz software é mais importante testar o que não funciona. Testar é difícil porque nem sempre se sabe tudo o que precisa ser testado. Fazendo uma analogia, neste caso você está tentando descobrir se o nome da pessoa está grafado corretamente. É impossível saber, é um problema da pessoa e não seu problema saber o que é correto.

Me impressiona que mesmo aqui todo mundo, inclusive eu, apresentam soluções simplificadas, ingênuas, sem testes extensivos, que provavelmente as pessoas que fizeram, se são conscientes, não utilizariam em seus códigos sem uma análise mais profunda, mas quem lê sai usando como se a solução fosse perfeita.

Programar é difícil, existem muitas variantes que precisam ser analisadas, sem entender todo o fundamento problema, principalmente de segurança, vão ocorrer aos montes.

Hoje existem campanhas para introduzir novos programadores na indústria. Elas têm dois objetivos: 1) criar consumidores para ferramentas de programação, não importa que resultados aconteçam, inclusive porque programação errada também faz a indústria se movimentar; 2) achar qualidade na quantidade, afinal há uma esperança que todos os novos programadores vão procurar entender os fundamentos e todos os aspectos necessários.

Então questione tudo o que lê na internet, até mesmo o que lê aqui. Aqui temos pessoas validando as respostas, mas é comum as pessoas terem um senso crítico baixo e nem sempre essa validação ocorre como deveria. As pessoas têm uma tendência a querer agradar mais do que fazer o certo e todo mundo sai prejudicado com isto. Podemos chamar isto de populismo profissional. Elas querem criar uma aparência de estarem ajudando.

Aqui ainda é o local com mais probabilidade de obter uma resposta mais consistente e ir se desenvolvendo, mas ainda assim recomendo estudar o funcionamento dos protocolos, usar um analisador de pacotes para ver como os dados são trafegados, tentar forjar os dados de todas as formas. Isto ninguém poderá fazer por você. Sempre que achar um problema e não souber como resolver, deve procurar fontes (no plural) confiáveis e verificáveis.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Conceptual.md).

Answer (score 1):

Mas os dados do formulário vão ser enviados para o seu próprio servidor ou para um servidor de terceiros ? Se for para seu próprio servidor, acho que o que você pode fazer é estabelecer regras de valores aceitos quando for pegar os dados no servidor e retornar um erro caso os dados não estejam dentro das regras. Se for para um servidor de terceiros, teria que ver se não dava para enviar para o seu servidor e depois enviar para o servidor de destino (validação, como o colega de cima disse).